# SSL validation fails, after applying SUSE-SLE-Module-Public-Cloud-12-2020-251

Tags: linux, command-line, ssl, aws, sles

Post applying the following OS patch SUSE-SLE-Module-Public-Cloud-12-2020-251 (Security Update for aws-cli) for the month of Feb 2020, AWS CLI was throwing the error SSL validation failed. The command was working fine before applying the OS security patch 
Does anybody knows how to fix this issue?

```
aws s3 ls s3://

SSL validation failed for https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My OS details: 
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12-SP4"
VERSION_ID="12.4"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP4"

aws cli version: 
aws --version  aws-cli/1.16.297 Python/2.7.13
Linux/4.12.14-95.45-default botocore/1.12.213

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upgrade of aws-cli fixed the issue. Below commands, I ran and got the issue resolved.

> zypper in python-pip
>
> pip install --upgrade awscli
>
> aws --version
>
> aws-cli/1.17.17 Python/2.7.13 Linux/4.12.14-95.6-default botocore/1.14.17